# Multiple frame ancestors in CSP overriten by X FRAME option

Tags: content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am having some issues setting security policies for my UI which can be framed by more than one site. I am setting CSP policy with multiple frame ancestors. Adding XFrame option is mandated so if I leave it empty the parent class rendering all UIs will add XFO SAMEORIGIN which contradicts with CSP frame ancestors.

One option is to use ALLOWALL but that is not supported widely. Is there any other way I can set an X Frame Option but  allow from multiple Uris?

Comment: I am facing this issue mainly cause I cannot modify the parent class behavior.

Comment: Note that frame-ancestors will not take priority in firefox, see this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024557 and upvote it to try get this fixed. And of course they don't work at all in any Microsoft browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply an invalid value, X-Frame-Options will basically be ignored allowing this to fallback to the frame ancestors you are providing.

Since it can be any value, have fun:

```
X-Frame-Options: totally chill
```